# jquery.js передача параметра с кирилицей

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Есть таблица, пример: http://lavds-wordpress.tw1.ru/test2/

Если заголовок столбца на английском, то все работает.

Если на русском, то ошибка *syntax error, unrecognized expression: #tab%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba*.

Как передать кириллицу и где что надо изменить?

Comment: а зачем выпередаёте в href="" кирилицу? нет возможности передать значение href латиницей?

Comment: спасибо понял. переделал на латиницу в id таблиц

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из коментов, простым решением будет просто передавать параметр в HREF - латиницей.